# d3 chart resize doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make a responsive chart.

This is my code :

```
var width = (parseInt(d3.select('#'+chartID).style('width'), 10));

...

d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
    // Recalculate
    width = parseInt(d3.select('#'+chartID).style('width'), 10);
    d3.select(svg.node().parentNode).style('width', (width) + 'px');
});
```

It doesn't set style attributes to the SVG. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for "answering", I don't have points for commenting. I can delete this after you read:

Check if your "svg" is a group (g) element. Maybe something like this:

```
var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .style('width', (width + margin.left + margin.right) + 'px')
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [margin.left, margin.top] + ')');
```

In this case, you need parentNode to get the actual svg, that is the parent of your group.

But if your "svg" is not a g, remove parentNode.